# Using xdotool to locate click and apply appropriate action

Tags: linux, bash, x11

I would like to have xdotool detect if a right-click is on a particular window (I can capture window IDs without problem), and then run the appropriate shell command/function, if the click was on the desired window..

In real terms this means I want xdotool to get the window ID of a VLC video playback window, and then to run a specific command if I right click on that window.

I am using BASH 4.2.0(1)-release, and Xdotool 2.20101012.3049

EDIT: This is as close as I have got, but it does not work:

```
xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ mouse-click exec 'myscript'
```

However, these commands DO work, but is not really what I need:

```
xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ mouse-enter exec 'myscript'

xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ mouse-leave exec 'myscript'
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Something like following might work:

```
xdotool behave 18893317 mouse-click exec '/usr/bin/bash -c "echo hi"'
```

However xdotool doesn't work for arbitrary applications. You could try to read mouse events directly using: [evdev.py](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/source/browse/trunk/src/lib/evdev.py?r=520)

```
ls -l /dev/input/by-id/usb-062a_0000-event-mouse 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2011-12-21 18:05 /dev/input/by-id/usb-062a_0000-event-mouse -> ../event4
evdev.py /dev/input/event4
```

When you get click you can use coordinates to determine if it's within VLC window (by comparing with coordinates returned by xdotool).

Comment: Hmm, upon further investigation, this does not work:

`xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ mouse-click exec 'myscript'`

But this DOES work:

`xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ mouse-enter exec 'myscript'`

But that is no good, I need 'mouse-click' to work...

Comment: http://myfreebsd.homeunix.net/freebsd/mouse_events_shell.html seems to have some answers, but yet to apply or find the relevant stuff!

Comment: I don't think [mouse_events_shell](http://myfreebsd.homeunix.net/freebsd/mouse_events_shell.html) would work (it shouldn't give you coordinates outside of xterm window). Did you consider using [evdev.py](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/source/browse/trunk/src/lib/evdev.py) as described earlier?

Comment: I realised pretty quick that mouse_events_shell would not help me... And no, I didn't try evdev.py, because I don't have python installed, and neither do the systems on which my script is to be installed..

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old thread, but man xdotool SENDEVENT NOTES explains (implicitly) why 'mouse-click' may not work.
Alternatively, using 'focus' instead of 'mouse-click' does work for a user mouse click.
Note that the command
`xdotool search --name "VLC" behave %@ focus exec 'myscript'`
may not terminate, but remain active. At least this is true for the way I am trying to use it, to set cropping locations in imagemagic, thus
`xdotool search --name "imagemagic" behave %@ focus getmouselocation`